# Is there an API for creating/modifying GDAP relationships?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Has anyone found any APIs to automate creating/updating GDAP relationships or do we still need to do everything in the GUI?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/delegatedadminrelationships-api-overview?view=graph-rest-beta

This page is misleading because it has "GDAP" listed at the top level however everything it mentions is DAP related.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that these DAP endpoints do actually work for GDAP relationships, you need to generate the tokens with relevant permissions at your partner center tenant level and it should let you perform all needed tasks for creation/update of GDAP relationships.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/delegatedadminrelationships-api-overview?view=graph-rest-beta